# ExecuteUpdateAsync: Could not be translated

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0, bulkupdate, ef-core-7.0

I'm facing an issue trying to perform a bulk update through EFCore 7 `ExecuteUpdateAsync()` method.

The error message says:

> .ExecuteUpdate(calls => calls.SetProperty(
> propertyExpression: x => x.Meter.StatusId,
> valueExpression: x => x.NewStatusId))' could not be translated.
> Additional information: The following 'SetProperty' failed to translate: 'SetProperty(x => x.Meter.StatusId, x => x.NewStatusId)'.  See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)

I have an abstract entity `BaseMeter` which implements this public method to retrieve another Entity `MeterStatusType` which is abstract as well and has a relationship with this `BaseMeter` entity

```cs
public MeterStatusType RecalculateStatus() =>
    StartDate.Date <= DateTime.Today &&
    (!EndDate.HasValue ||
     DateTime.Today <= EndDate.Value.Date)
        ? MeterStatusType.Live
        : MeterStatusType.Disused;
```

And this is my `ExecuteUpdateAsync`:

```cs
await _dbContext.Set<BaseMeter>()
    .Select(m => new
    {
        Meter = m,
        NewStatusId = m.RecalculateStatus().Id
    })
    .ExecuteUpdateAsync(calls => calls.SetProperty(x => x.Meter.StatusId, x => x.NewStatusId),
        cancellationToken);
```

I have done it following the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/execute-insert-update-delete#navigations-and-related-entities) and the EFCore version being used is the 7.0.15.

Could anyone throw some light into this please?

Comment: @GertArnold from what I can infer from this, OP is trying to achieve that EF Core performs an UPDATE SET StatusId = CASE... where the value to set to the StatusId field is calculated with a CASE evaluation depending on other fields from the same record. That should be perfectly doable in SQL, but I can see the challenge is on how to achieve this in EF Core, in order to not require that any client-side evaluation takes place (which shouldn't).
What OP is doing is similar to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/execute-insert-update-delete#navigations-and-related-entities

Comment: I'm a ef core n00b, but shouldn't the whole property be a calculated column, if one uses db first.

Comment: @siggemannen I think a computed column is a viable alternative, unless (as always) the computation needs to be done at specific time intervals. Something for OP to consider.

Comment: @siggemannen a computed column would only change its value when one of the fields it depends on change their value... From what I can infer, the OP is expecting to keep the StatusId updated based on the current day (hence the use of DateTime.Today as the reference for the dates), so that value won't just update based on the current date... Some value would need to be updated for the StatusId to change and it doesn't look like the idea of the OP.

Comment: @GertArnold but values don't seem to be client-side generated and it should be doable with one update statement... That's what I'm pointing out of your comment.

Comment: It seems there's some sort of join going on if i understand the description, so perhaps it's not possible to use calculated column at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Core cannot translate a bare C# function. It can only translate an `Expression` or an `IQueryable`.

You could probably use Expressions with a Visitor, but the easiest method is probably to just create a new type with `IQueryable`

```cs
public class MeterStatusUpdate
{
    public Meter Meter { get; set; }
    public MeterStatusType NewStatusId { get; set; }
}

public static IQueryable<MeterStatusUpdate> RecalculateStatus(this IQueryable<Meter> source) =>
    source.Select(m => new MeterStatusUpdate {
        Meter = m,
        NewStatusId = m.StartDate.Date <= DateTime.Today
          && (!m.EndDate.HasValue || DateTime.Today <= m.EndDate.Value.Date)
        ? MeterStatusType.Live
        : MeterStatusType.Disused
    });
```

Then use it like this

```cs
await _dbContext
    .Set<BaseMeter>()
    .RecalculateStatus()
    .ExecuteUpdateAsync(calls => calls
        .SetProperty(x => x.Meter.StatusId, x => x.NewStatusId),
        cancellationToken);
```

Note that you can't re-embed an `IQueryable` inside another one. Either use a separate variable for that, or switch to Expressions.

---

An alternative, if that doesn't work, is to embed the whole calculation inside `ExecuteUpdateAsync`

```cs
await _dbContext
    .Set<BaseMeter>()
    .ExecuteUpdateAsync(calls => calls
        .SetProperty(x => x.StatusId, x =>
            x.StartDate.Date <= DateTime.Today
            && (!x.EndDate.HasValue || DateTime.Today <= x.EndDate.Value.Date)
            ? MeterStatusType.Live
            : MeterStatusType.Disused,
        cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Isn't this pretty much the same as the OP already displayed in the question? He's performing a .Select(...) to project the same data you're projecting into a record, but instead into an anonymous object, then passing the resulting IQueryable<a'> to the ExecuteUpdateAsync(...)... How's that any different?

Comment: I'm suffering the exact same error, and in fact the only things that changes is that instead of Selecting an anonymous type it gets into a dedicated Record, right?

Comment: @CesarD No, this is using an `IQueryable`, where the `Select` function accepts an `Expression`, not a `Func`. In OP's case, it was using a bare C# function, which is never going to work. I'm not sure why it's not working, I have used this technique many times.

Comment: @Gonzo345 No it's not the same. As mentioned, it now uses a full `IQueryable` expression, not a plain function. It needs to be a `static` function which gets all its data from the existing `IQueryable`.

Comment: @GertArnold It is perfectly possible to make calculations *within* the `ExecuteUpdate`, you just can't have data coming in from outside at the same time. The first suggestion I used should also work, as the calculation is done within the expression, not in a separate function.

Comment: @Charlieface I don't see any difference: the Select he was applying in the question is already accepting an Expression, not just a Func, and it's performed over the IQueryable<BaseMeter> that is returned by the .Set<BaseMeter>(). Then, the Select returns another IQueryable<a'>, which is similar to what you're doing by returning a IQueryable<MeterStatusUpdate>. You're merely encapsulating pretty much the same code into a method, and switching an anonymous type by a record, but the rest is pretty much the same.

The last thing you've just edited might work, but haven't tested it.

Comment: Although, I suspect it might not work due to the ternary operator used in the SetProperty() method... I'm not sure EF Core can translate that correctly into SQL straight from that LINQ.

Comment: @CesarD The original code called a custom C# function within the Expression `.Select(m => new { Meter = m, NewStatusId = m.RecalculateStatus().Id })` which is not supported. What I'm doing is creating a new `IQueryable` based on the original, and no functions are called within the `Select`

Comment: A little bit of testing shows that I was wrong in assuming that only the last alternative could work. I could do something like the first query, even using an anonymous type. Time to remove my previous comments and sorry for causing confusion.

Comment: I've done some testing too and indeed, the last alternative presented here doesn't work for the reason I mentioned: the ternary operator is not recognized by EF Core as something translatable into SQL within the ExecuteUpdateAsync, same as trying to call the RecalculateStatus() even in the Select, because it's a delegate that cannot be translated into an expression tree, so the only viable fix is indeed the first one which is to write all the code from RecalculateStatus() method into the Select; record or anonymous object both work and don't make any difference from each other.